# Encrypted traffic from Kafka to .NET Consumer

Tags: encryption, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a .NET client (using Confluent .NET Kafka) as consumer on Kafka topic. Now I want to encrypt the traffic. I am looking for lightweight solution to do it. Any experience? Shall I stick with SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS should work fine. Otherwise you'd write your own Serializer / Deserializer classes to do encryption

Answer (score 1):

Beware that you might encrypt the traffic but data at rest will not be encrypted in Kafka. The only way to actually encrypt the messages is doing that on the client side.

There are some higher level libraries that will do that for you. For example Silverback (my library): https://silverback-messaging.net/concepts/broker/encryption.html